# How can I webcast a live drawing session with Android?

Tags: drawing

I just migrated from an iPad to a Nexus 7. One app that I used frequently was [Jot](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/jot!-whiteboard-free/id371937922?mt=8). Basically it was a simple drawing app that allowed people to watch what I was drawing in real time on a webpage.

Is there a way to achieve something similar on Android?

Answer (score 1):

**To the date, No**

The best you can get is to share your whiteboard through Wi-Fi. Go to goolge play store and search for [whiteboard apps](https://play.google.com/store/search?q=whiteboard&c=apps). You will find a plenty of great apps.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

We created an app that allows you draw + chat with multiple users in real-time.

It's also a social network so can add friends, upload stuff, view a newsfeed etc.

Market: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.che.squibble.client

Website: https://www.squibblebox.com

Let us know what you think!